# Getting the max date of a column where another column does not equal zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the most recent activity date that a user has provided activity as part of a query. Here is the query:

```
USE SCRUMAPI2

DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@statusParam VARCHAR(100)

SET @userParam = '%'
SET @statusParam = '%'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY TSK.[Status] DESC
        ) AS 'RowNumber'
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    ) THEN 'KanBan' WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 'Sprint' END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,STY.Title AS StoryTitle
    ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS Effort
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS OriginalEstimateHours
    ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS [TotalHours]
    ,TSK.[Status] AS [Status]
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND TSK.[Status] LIKE @statusParam
GROUP BY LEN(STY.[Number])
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.[Status]
    ,STY.Title
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,TSK.CreateDate
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,STY.KanBanProductId
    ,STY.SprintId
    ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
    ,STY.Effort
ORDER BY CASE TSK.[Status] WHEN 'Not Started' THEN 1 WHEN 'In Progress' THEN 2 WHEN 'Impeded' THEN 3 WHEN 'Done' THEN 4 END
```

I would like to add a row with functionality like so:

```
,MAX(DTH.ActivityDate WHERE DTH.Hours != 0) AS LatestActivityDate
```

This however results in a syntax error. I can't add  DTH.Hours != 0 to the WHERE statement because I don't want the whole query filtered by it. So how do I get the most recent ActivityDate where Hours does not equal zero?

Here is what the DTH table looks like for reference:

[image]

Comment: try using a subquery with self join `,(select MAX(DTH2.ActivityDate) from DailyTaskHours DTH2 WHERE dth.taskID=dth2.taskID and DTH2.Hours != 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is our friend:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN DTH.Hours != 0 THEN DTH.ActivityDate END) AS LatestActivityDate
```